# Nil(R) is an exact category

Tags: category-theory, modules, projective-module, higher-category-theory

The definition of an exact category as I have read is a pair ($\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{E}$) is an exact category if the additive category $\mathcal{C}$ is embedded as a full subcategory inside an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, $\mathcal{E}$ is the collection of all sequence in $\mathcal{C}$ of the form $$0\rightarrow A_2\rightarrow A_1\rightarrow A_0\rightarrow 0$$ which are exact in $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ is closed under extension in $\mathcal{A}$.

Now Nil($R$) is the category that has objects as pairs ($P, \nu$) where $P$ is finitely generated projective $R$ module and $\nu$ is a nilpotent endomorphism of $P$.

Now I have been told that it is an exact category, but I am finding it difficult to establish an abelian category such that Nil($R$) embeds inside it as a full subcategory.

I understand that $P(R) $ the category of finitely generated projective $R$ module can be embedded in the category of $R$ modules and can be shown exact but as I have mentioned earlier I am finding the embedding part difficult to prove.
Any hints or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: If one drops the requirements that $P$ be f.g. projective and $\nu$ be nilpotent, then one would get the category of all $R[x]$-modules ($R[x]$ is the polynomial ring).

Comment: I think I got the answer. Nil($R$) can be embedded in $Endo(R)$ where I am defining the objects as $(M, \alpha)$ where $M$ is any $R$ module and $\alpha$ is an endomorphism of $M$. This category is additive as $(0,0)$ and $\times$ is there and is satisfying all the other properties. I will formalize an answer to this and post it if it is correct

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang sir, I am a bit confused so will it be a categorical equivalence?